How to get TIA DC BIAS lower
I am currently working on a TIA circuit. Against most TIA circuits, I used a reverse voltage over the photodiode, which is needed to lower its capacitance (eventually given a higher signal bandwidth for higher speed), but creates dark current leakage. I first used a AC coupling capacitor at the output, but now I need a DC bias to be able to sample with a STM microcontrollers ADC (It looks like it can handle 0-3.3V). The DC bias needs to be lowered, but the op amp then stops working / works worse. How can this be solved and what is causing this?
A not nice solution from my side would be a voltage divider. The first figure shows 6V Dc bias that works, but I want then something like 2V DC bias like figure 2 but then working (simulation still works kind of but real circuit not). Help would be appreciated :).
I took in account the stability calculations of the TIA and made sure to have a phase margin of at least 45.



I've rolled back your question to how it was when I answered it. I'm pleased that you took the trouble of checking that my answer was correct but, regarding the new question (now rolled back to your original), this needs to be addressed in a new post (with the added benefit that it becomes open to the floor and not just in this limited corner of the site).


The DC bias needs to be lowered, but the op amp then stops working /
works worse. How can this be solved and what is causing this?

The LF357 is unable to handle input voltages that are within 3 volts of the negative rail (0 volts in your circuit). It's all there in the data sheet on page 7: -


Hey Andy, thank you very much that makes sense. :) I have added the question and how would you then create the negative supply, given a 12V dc power supply and STM32L432KC, see figure 4? Or would another op amp solve this problem easier?

@Visje999 I've rolled back your question to how it was when I answered it. I'm pleased that you took the trouble of checking that my answer was correct but, regarding the new question (now rolled back to your original), this needs to be addressed in a new post.  If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
